# simple angular function explanation needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a simple angular function. The purpose is to display a changing value of variable x after pressing a button which triger the function startAction. It is not working and I have no idea why.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myController', ($scope, fabryka) => {

$scope.startAction = function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var x = 0;
        $scope.x = (function () {
            x++;
            return x;
        })();
    }, 500);
    }      
});
```

Comment: why you had `interval` as you wanted to update value on click of button?

Comment: You probably need to move `var x = 0` to above `setInterval`

Comment: Please also show how you are using this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular has its own setInterval wrapper: `$interval`.

This piece of code counts seconds as you press the button. Please note the interval cancellation when the scope is destroyed.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.x = 0;

    var interval;

    vm.startAction = function() {
      vm.isRunning = true;
      interval = $interval(function() {
        vm.x++;
      }, 1000);
    };

    vm.stopAction = function() {
      vm.isRunning = false;
      $interval.cancel(interval);
    }

    $scope.$on('$destroy', vm.stopAction);

    return this;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
  <div>x: {{vm.x}}</div>
  <button ng-click="!vm.isRunning? vm.startAction():vm.stopAction()">{{vm.isRunning? 'Pause':'Start'}}</button>
</div>
```